# How to render specific edges of a cube different from filling in XNA? (Monogame)

Tags: c#, xna, shader, monogame, edges

I am working with C#, Monogame and XNA 4.0. In my scene I have a lot of cubes. Some are connected, some are not. I would like to render the edges of the cube with another shader than the filling. Besides that, I would like to render the outer edges of connected cubes in another color (or thicker) than the edges within the cube-object. Here is a small painting to make clear what I want to do (sorry for my bad painting skills, but I think you will get it).

[image: Desired Results]

1. I know how to render a cube with a specific shader and I am also able to render the wireframe but I was not able to connect both methods. Besids that, the outer lines can not be rendered differently with this approach.
2. I tried it with post-effects like the edgefinding of comic shaders but in this approach I am not able render only specific edges. Besides that if two cubes are next to each other the shader does not recognize the edges.

I am not searching for a ready-to-use solution from you but I would be glad to get some tips/approaches/tutorials/similar projects/etc on how to achieve my goal. Are there some shader experts out there? I am at my wit's end.

(If you however would like to post a ready to use solution I would not be miffy :D)

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame you're not using deferred shading, this would be pretty straight forward to implement if you were.

If you can access the normal and material for each pixel on screen through a texture lookup you can easily post-process this. You could use a 3x3 filter kernel and search for sufficiently large normal discontinuities (this would catch silhouette edges) and also search for pixels that lie on the transition between material IDs (this would catch the edges between blue and orange cubes). If your filter neighborhood satisfied either of these two conditions, then draw a black pixel to form the outline.

You should be able to do this if you use MRT rendering when you draw your cubes, and encode the normal + material ID into an RGBA texture (x,y,z,material).

The basic theory is described in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.4558&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pp. 13). In this case instead of using the depth as the secondary characteristic for outlining, you would use the material (or object ID, if you want EVERY cube to have an outline).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sounds complicated to me for now but i will read the paper and give it a try as far i get back from work. What i don't understand in this situation - how would i render the red outline then? In the shader i don't know if a pixel is on the upper edge or on a side one.

Comment: Yeah, this is somewhat complicated. I tend to tackle these sorts of problems using image processing techniques because I work so heavily with deferred shading. As for coloring outlines differently, the beauty of this approach is that you have two separate conditions in your search filter, you can assign a different color (or even a combination of both colors) depending on which condition passes.

Comment: Since you are more interested in coloring the exterior edges different from cube/cube edges, I would actually suggest you use the eye space depth and cube ID in your texture. You will still look for discontinuities, its just these two properties would probably give you the results from your sample image.

Comment: Seems that i messed up my whole project yesterday, so it can take a while until i can report back if i got it working. Anyways thank you for your efforts.